# Stage Size in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn how to animate in javascript and I was just wondering is there a stage size or window size in javascript so once elements go off the "stage" they are no longer seen just like in flash. Any help in explaining this would be great as I just started learning Javascript and was a bit confused about this.

Comment: Flash and Javascript are _nothing_ alike and have absolutely nothing in common. Best to start avoiding comparing them right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever element contains your animated elements you can add a css rule to hide anything which goes "off stage"

```
#myStage {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you're coming from a flash background it might be better for you to get to know a canvas library such as [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com) as it's far more self-contained than using a mixture of plain js, css & html.